# Rails-Schedule on tuesday and friday using whenever

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, whenever

I am using whenever for scheduling in my rails app.
I could not find how to run my cronjobs on every tuesday and friday of the week anywhere in the gem's documentation.

This is what I am doing right now is this correct?

```
every [:tuesday, :friday], at: '12:00am', :roles => [:my_role] do
  runner "User.notify"
end
```

Comment: you test out on local machine and let us know.

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon how to test?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the plain crontab syntax in the `schedule.rb`

```
every '0 0 * * 2,5', :roles => [:my_role] do
  runner "User.notify"
end
```

`'0 0 * * 2,5'` - “At 12:00 on Tuesday and Friday.”

It's pretty simple:

```
Minute   Hour    Day of Month       Month          Day of Week
(0-59)  (0-23)     (1-31)    (1-12 or Jan-Dec)  (0-6 or Sun-Sat)
 0        0         *                *               2,5
```

<sub>Refs for help [`1`](https://crontab.guru/), [`2`](https://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html)</sub>

Comment: Good answer! But he wants "12:00am" so better would be '0 0 * * 2,5'